# What is the name of the <=> operator in Ruby? What do they call it?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, spaceship-operator

In Ruby there is the `<=>` operator. In the API they do not name its name, just:

> The class must define the <=> operator...
>
> Comparable uses <=> to implement the conventional comparison...
>
> ...the objects in the collection must also implement a meaningful <=> operator...

What is its name?

Answer (score 5):

See @Tony's above. However, it's also called (in slang) the "spaceship operator".

Answer (score 4):

It's called the **Combined Comparison Operator**

> Combined comparison operator. Returns 0 if first operand equals second, 1 if first operand is greater than the second and -1 if first operand is less than the second.

```
(a <=> b) returns -1.
```

Comment: That's what it's called, but nobody calls it that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: We call it the "spaceship"!

Comment: @Linuxios We’re more addicted to real life, so we call it “nunchaku”. But “spaceship” will be my fave from now on.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Who's "we" in this case?

Comment: @Linuxios We with colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the combined comparison operator. Returns 0 if first operand equals second, 1 if first operand is greater than the second and -1 if first operand is less than the second.

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Ive also heard it just called the double hash rocket